# Excel - data validation to return multiple values

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use a VLookup function to return a number of personal details for an employee who's name is selected from a list (drop down on data validation), for example, on the employee sheet, columns would contain:-

First Name
Surname
Phone Number 
Employment status

And the data for each employee contained on the various rows.

By using a drop down box on a secondary sheet to validate employee surname, but then a secondary drop to verify (thereby preventing two employees with the same surname confusing issues), I'd like to bring up the remainder of details...

I'm getting lost in the trying to do this!!! And possibly haven't explained it too well...sorry

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, you want a drop-down box that contains all the surnames.
After the user choose the surname, there will be another drop-down box that contains all the 1st name of those who have the chosen surname.
VBA would be my choice.
But I think in excel-only, you can use another table(in a hidden sheet e.g.), which VLookups all the 1st names by the chosen surname. Your 2nd drop-down box would point to this list of 1st name.
Other data can be looked-up using the 1st name and surname.